# My quick sort implementation is not working for 10000 sequence numbers

Tags: java, algorithm

I have a quick sort implementation, this sort implementation is working fine with small arrays and 10000 random numbers but it is throwing a stackoverflow error when the input was 10000 sequence numbers (from 1 to 10000)

```
public class QuickSort<T extends Comparable> extends Sort<T>{

public void sort(Comparable[] input) {
    sort(input, 0, input.length-1);
}

private void sort(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    if (hi <= lo) return;

    int j = partition(a, lo, hi);
    sort(a, lo, j-1);
    sort(a, j+1, hi);
}

private int partition(Comparable[] a, int lo, int hi) {
    int i=lo;
    int j=hi + 1;
    Comparable v = a[lo];

    while(true) {
        while (less(a[++i], v)) {
            if (i == hi) break;
        }

        while (less(v, a[--j])) {
            if (j == lo) break;
        }

        if(i >= j) break;

        exch(a, i, j);
    }
    exch(a, lo, j);
    return j;
}

public static boolean less (Comparable a, Comparable b) {
    return a.compareTo(b) < 0;
}

public static void exch(Comparable[] array, int i, int j) {
    Comparable temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[j];
    array[j] = temp;
}

public static void main(String...args) {
    Integer[] array = new Integer[] {10,2,9,11,1,19,9,4,6,2,1,4,5,6};
    new QuickSort<>().sort(array);

    for (int temp : array) {
        System.out.print(temp + " ");
    }
}
}
```

It is working for 10000 random numbers and for other input. But throws a stackoverflow error when executed with 10000 sequence numbers (from 1 to 10000)

Comment: Note: you shouldn't be using `Comparable` inside your `QuickSort` class, you should be using `T`. And `T` should be declared as `T extends Comparable<T>`.

Comment: not coding in JAVA but is there a heap/stack limit like in most compilers? if yes try to enlarge it in something like project options to value you need but do not expect that recursive algorithm is boundless... you got 3 calls per recursion layer each with 3 operands (hoping the array is just pointer) so do the math . Also include all local variables so 4*int

Comment: @Spektre And Java helpfully throws a `StackOverflowError` when ... yes, you guessed it, the stack overflows. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple Quicksort implementation has O(n^2) complexity and O(n) additional memory requirements in the worst-case scenario. You've got this worst-case on ordered sequence because of bad pivot element selection method.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort#Choice_of_pivot):

> In the very early versions of quicksort, the leftmost element of the
>   partition would often be chosen as the pivot element. Unfortunately,
>   this causes worst-case behavior on already sorted arrays, which is a
>   rather common use-case. The problem was easily solved by choosing
>   either a random index for the pivot, choosing the middle index of the
>   partition or (especially for longer partitions) choosing the median of
>   the first, middle and last element of the partition for the pivot (as
>   recommended by Sedgewick).

Simple way to fix this issue is to take middle element as a pivot. Replace

```
Comparable v = a[lo];
```

with

```
Comparable v = a[lo+(hi-lo)/2];
```

It is not that hard to create worst-case test for this pivot selection method, but you'll need to do it intentionally on large input cases. If you want sorting algorithm that is similar to Quicksort and without O(n^2) worst-cases, you should look at [Introsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introsort) algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

The stack overflow occurs because you indeed more try to use more stack space then is available for your java program in the JVM.

This happens because your pivot-selection strategy is simply selecting the first element as a pivot, and this causes a worst-case performance when the array is already sorted - in this case the algorithm runs in O(n^2) time and O(n) space - which means the recursion is 10000 deep, using up more stack than available.

You have a few options :

1. **Increase stack space** - Default stack size (in most JVMs) in 512k, but you can change this with the `-Xss` flag. In my env, when I added the flag `-Xss18m` (18 MB) I could run the program with an array of 200k without stack overflow. You can increase it even much more than that.
2. **Try to use less stack space** - stack space is used by the recursion and the stack variables which are defined in the function.

   For example, you could change the array itself to be a member of the class `QuickSort`, and not pass it as a parameter. This would add only two integers (lo and hi) to the stack in each call, and save up stack space.
3. **(The best option) - Use a random pivot** - Select a random element between `lo` and `hi` as pivot, not always the first one.
   instead of

   `Comparable v = a[p];`

use

```
 int p = lo + r.nextInt(hi  - lo);
 Comparable v = a[p];
```

and in the end

```
exch(a, p, j);
```